# What should I name my overriding render-function?

Tags: routes, theming

I'm just starting out with drupal and need some custom html for an intricate menu system. My plan is to override the html-generating functions in template.php.

My theme name is "Drupal subtheme" and the navbar I would like to target has the machine name "menu-usm-navbar-small". What should I name the functions that overrides the default html-printouts?

I think I have tried every possible combination of these. Some examples of what I've tried:

```
function drupal_subtheme_menu_link($variables) {
    return "foo";
}

function drupal_subtheme__menu_usm_navbar_small($variables) {
    return "foo";
}
```

Comment: If your theme's machine name is `drupal_subtheme`, your first example is right. You should clear the caches, at least clear the theme-registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to target.

If it's the tree of the menu you can use [theme_menu_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) :

```
function drupal_subtheme_menu_tree__menu__menu_usm_navbar_small($variables) {
   return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

if it's the link, you can use [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) :

```
function drupal_subtheme_menu_link__menu__menu_usm_navbar_small($variables) {
   $element = $variables['element'];
   $sub_menu = '';

   if ($element['#below']) {
     $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
   }
   $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
   return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

These functions need to be in template.php

Comment: I tried these examples but it did not work. The ul element still has the classes "menu nav" even though I replaced your class="menu" with class="menu hello hello".

Comment: The cache is cleared.

Comment: Is your theme activated and set defaut ? What do you get in the URL when you try to edit your menu "menu-usm-navbar-small" ? And what do you get in the URL when you edit your theme ?

Comment: It is set to default and the url in Adminpanel > Menu > USM Navbar Small is http://localhost/usm/?q=node#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fstructure%252Fmenu%252Fmanage%252Fmenu-usm-navbar-small

Comment: I made an update, can you try it ? I added __menu__ (drupal_subtheme_menu_tree__menu__menu_usm_navbar_small)

Comment: Yep, it works now. But it was not them 'menu'. I mixed up "drupal" and "bootstrap" in the name. Well spent afternoon indeed... Correct version is thus: bootstrap_subtheme_menu_link__menu__menu_usm_navbar_small. Apologies for wasting your time :/

Comment: No problem ;-) It's always on the little things we waist the most times :-D